# Only one item is appearing at a time on list view

Tags: list, listview, dart, flutter

I cant seem to figure out how to get all of my items in my list to display in the list view

Currently, when I click my button to display the list, only one items shows up. If I click back, and click main button again, it shows 2 items from the list. Rinse and repeat, 3 items. I can't seem to debug with print statements to see where my error lies. When I try print(trails) or other variations, it says Instance of trail model (not very helpful). Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```dart
class HomeScreen extends State<MyApp> {
  int counter = 0;
  Future<List<TrailModel>> fetchData() async {
    counter++;
    var response = await get(
        'https://www.hikingproject.com/data/get-trails?lat=39.733694&lon=-121.854771&maxDistance=10&key=200419778-6a46042e219d019001dd83b13d58aa59');

    final trailModel = TrailModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    //trails.add(trailModel);
    setState(() {
      trails.add(trailModel);
    });

    return trails;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("HikeLocator")),
      body: new RaisedButton(
        child: Text("click me"),
        onPressed: () async {
          final trails = await fetchData();
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new ListScreen(trails)),
          );
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class ListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<TrailModel> trails;
  ListScreen(this.trails);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Here are your trails"),
      ),
      body: TrailList(trails),
    );
  }
}

class TrailList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<TrailModel> trails;

  TrailList(this.trails);

  Widget build(context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: trails.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
        Object myText = json.encode(trails[index].trails);

        List<dynamic> myText2 = json.decode(myText);

        return Text(myText2[index]['name']);
      },
    );
  }
}

class TrailModel {
  Object trails;
  TrailModel(this.trails);
  TrailModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    trails = parsedJson['trails'];
  }
}
```

I think my problem might lie in the fetchData(), but I'm not entirely sure. Trying to at least print out the values to limit where my problem might be. (Is it only adding 1 to the list each time I press the button? Is it only rendering one when I click it? Is it fetching all the data each click or only one json object? etc.)

Thank you kindly for any assistance. Sorry, I'm kind of new to dart, so this is a huge learning curve for

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems in your code. The main reason this doesn't work as you expect is because you're parsing all elements of the json into one `TrailModel` object, but then your code assumes that you'll have multiple `TrailModel` objects.

The easiest way to fix it up and get it working is to use the list from `TrailModel.trails` instead of the one in the widget.

First, in `ListScreen`, pass just the first element in the list.

```dart
class ListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<TrailModel> trails;
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
      ...
      body: TrailList(trails.first),
    );
  }
}
```

Then, in `TrailList`, use the `trails` list you have from `TrailModel`:

```dart
class TrailList extends StatelessWidget {
  final TrailModel model;
  TrailList(this.model);

  Widget build(context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: model.trails.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
        final trail = model.trails[index];
        ...
      },
    );
  }
}
```

> When I try print(trails) or other variations, it says Instance of trail model (not very helpful)

`print` uses the output of the `toString` method in your classes. You're seeing `Instance of trail model` because that's the default implementation you get from the super class `Object`. You can override it to get something more useful:

```dart
class TrailModel {
  @override
  String toString() => 'trails=$trails';
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. Still a few issues. First one is model.trails.length says getter not defined for the class Object. Makes sense, TrailModel's trails field is an object. So I made it a list of objects. No errors in IDE, so I ran it and got error on phone: first item displayed, then rangeError(index):Invalid value: only valid value is 0: 1. Then I thought, maybe in parsing the trails, I need to store in the indexes in the list, so I looped through the List of Objects I just created and parsed each one. This time, no output. Any additional assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you avoid using variables of type `Object` or `dynamic`, give an actual type to everything. With that you might be able to get going more easily with useful errors or with `print` debugging. Another thing you could do is go ask for help in gitter, you need some more personalized help than SO can offer.

Comment: Ok, thank you will you. Yeah that trails object is a json object, not sure what type I would name it, considering there's multiple types within there. I'm just grabbing 'name' for the time being until I can get everything working, then I can grab other pieces from it.